# load UICollectionViewCell to UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im trying to load UICollectionViewCell from .xib, to the UICollectionView, which is in reusable UIView also in .xib. This UIView will be loaded to more UIViewControllers. I found out, that I need load cell like this:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
```

but it will not load it.
I looked all around net for answer, but I couldn't find this specific case.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different cases,

1) If you're using storyboards and custom cells.

2) Nib and simple UIView(hierarchy of UIViews).

Yours seems to be the second case, 
First of all you need to make instance of a UICollectionView(by alloc init methods).
Then register the Nib holding your cell/view using following method.

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:CELL_IDENTIFIER bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
```

and then you can use that Nib using following method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *cell;
cell = (UICollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER
                                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
//Populate your data here.
return cell;
```

}

Hope this helps.. :)